# Recursively Removing Characters from a String using java

Tags: string, recursion

I am trying to write a program with recursive method that would do the following to a given string, "Sluggo".

```
Please enter a string: Sluggo
Sluggo
Slugg
Slug
Slu
Sl
S
luggo
lugg
lug
lu
l
uggo
ugg
ug
u
ggo
gg
g
go
g
o
```

This is my program so far:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class RecursiveDescentParser {


 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
   String s = input.next();

   chopBack(s.substring(0));
   chopBack(s.substring(1));
   chopBack(s.substring(2));
   chopBack(s.substring(3));
   chopBack(s.substring(4));
   chopBack(s.substring(5));
 }//end of main

 public static String chopBack(String str)
 {
   if (str.length() == 0)
      return "";
   else
      System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length()));
      return chopBack(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1 ));
 }
}
```

I know it's not right, because I need to write something similar to a double recursive method. Just wondering where I should go from this point? I have also written a method that would remove char from the front of the string. At this point I am not too sure how to connect the two together haha.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome, thank you guys!

Just played around with this a bit with a friend, and here is the solution he came up with in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a string:");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                //input = "Sluggo";
                initialLength = input.Length;
                recursiveFunctionYAY(input);
            }
        }

        static int initialLength;

        static void recursiveFunctionYAY(string input)
        {
            if (input.Length == 0)
                return;

            Console.WriteLine(input);
            recursiveFunctionYAY(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1));

            if (input.Length == initialLength)
            {
                initialLength = initialLength - 1;
                recursiveFunctionYAY(input.Substring(1, input.Length - 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
public String run(String input) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    process(input, sb);

    return sb.toString();
}

private void process(String input, StringBuilder sb) {

    tail(input, sb);

    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        return;
    }

    process(input.substring(1, input.length()), sb);
}

private void tail(String input, StringBuilder sb) {

    if (input.isEmpty())
        return;

    sb.append(input).append('\n');

    tail(input.substring(0, input.length() - 1), sb);
}
```

Comment: Looks awesome! I should really use string builder more often hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author JFVARUGH
 *
 */
public class RecursiveStringRem {

```
static String str ;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RecursiveStringRem drive = new RecursiveStringRem();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the String");
    str = sc.nextLine();
    drive.superStringCall(str);
}

public void  truncateSingleString(String str){
    // Base Condition
    if(str.length()==1){
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }

    // Recursive Call 
    System.out.println(str);
    // This will truncate the string by one position
    truncateSingleString(str.substring(1));         
}

public void superStringCall(String str){

    //Base Condition
    if(str.length()==1){
        return;
    }

    // Recursive Call 
    System.out.println(str);
    // This will call the previous function
    truncateSingleString(str.substring(1));

    // Recursive call in the current function
    superStringCall(str.substring(1));      
}
```

}

I guess the comments are self explanatory.

This is a complied code.

Comment: Looks good, but not quite the right output :)
Thanks for the inspiration tho! I guess making the str static would solve a lot of my problems!